# WCF: Is the order of elements in an XML that is posted to a Rest service important?

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization

I have been debugging a Rest Service for a while and I have realized that if I post (via POST method) this file

```
<RegionDTO xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/api">
 <id>4</id> 
 <country_id>1</country_id>
 <name>This is the name</name>
</RegionDTO>
```

I get this `RegionDTO` object populated:

RegionDTO.id --> 4
RegionDTO.name --> "This is the name"
RegionDTO.country_id --> **null**

And If I re-order the elements of this xml to this:

```
<RegionDTO xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/api">
<country_id>1</country_id>
<id>4</id> 
<name>This is the name</name>
</RegionDTO>
```

I get this `RegionDTO` object correctly populated:

RegionDTO.id --> 4
RegionDTO.name --> "This is the name"
RegionDTO.country_id --> **1**

Technical specification? .NET 4, self hosted

Comment: It's a bug, there is no logical explanation why order of attributes must matter

Comment: If the XML structure is defined as a `<xs:sequence>` - then yes!

Comment: Thanks for your comments! But where can I define the XML structure? in the same XML file or in the service?

Comment: Those aren't attributes. They're elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

The default serializer used by WCF is "DataContractSerializer". By default, Local elements are mapped in alphabetical order

Ref: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/Course/Toc.aspx?n=wcf-design-concepts (in "[DataContract] mapping" chapter)